# Rotating BufferedImage in Java without change size

Tags: java, image-processing, image-rotation

I am trying to rotating a BufferedImage in Java without changing size.
[image: First image] 
width = 232   height = 174

[image: After rotate]
width = 232   height = 174

I using this code but my image don`t rotate:

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.translate(four2.getWidth() / 2, four2.getHeight() / 2);
at.rotate(Math.PI/2);
at.scale(0.5, 0.5);
at.translate(-four2.getWidth()/2, -four2.getHeight()/2);
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) four2.getGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(four2, at, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

Comment: What do you mean "without changing size"?  The physical act of rotating an image will change the amount of space it requires.  Having said that though, whats `at.scale` for?

Comment: see images in qustion

Comment: Your second image should be `174x232`...

Comment: No. I want rotating without changing size

Comment: Then it will become cropped

Comment: I very tried to do but can`t. PLEASE write complete code for me. I`m beginner in java. very thanks

Comment: The moment some says "write complete code for me", I get really turned off, we're not a code writing service and you've provide less then 1% context to your problem, so any solution we might present, may not work.  better to arm yourself with a series of techniques which can be used in a verity of circumstances based available information, but that's just me...

Comment: You have to rotate the image and then concatenate it with a translation to 'move' the parts of the image that were shifted out of view back into view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating a non-square image within the same boundaries will crop the image.

You could change the `Graphics` clipping bounds, but this is dangerous, as you could actually end up painting outside of the visible bounds available to the `Graphics` context, which results in some very weird and generally not welcomed results.

A simpler solution might be to just generate a new image from the original and rotate it within it's own confines, for example...

[image: Rotated]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException iOException) {
                    iOException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage master;
        private BufferedImage rotated;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            master = ImageIO.read(new File("/Volumes/Disk02/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/issue142.jpg"));
            rotated = new BufferedImage(master.getWidth(), master.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = rotated.createGraphics();
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.rotate(Math.PI / 2, master.getWidth() / 2, master.getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.setTransform(at);
            g2d.drawImage(master, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(master.getWidth() * 2, master.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - (master.getWidth() * 2)) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - master.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(master, x, y, this);
            g2d.drawImage(rotated, x + master.getWidth(), y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```